# Yet another MessageSecurityException issue

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-binding

So I built a service which uses basic Auth Soap 1.2. Config below:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="MyHttpBinding">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" securityHeaderLayout="Strict"
        allowInsecureTransport="false">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" authenticationScheme="Basic" maxBufferSize="6553600" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

I have multiple clients calling it (WCF and Java). With WCF Client I do not have any issues, but with Java Client I get the following exception on server side:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException Security
>   processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This
>   might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is
>   a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur
>   if the service is configured for security and the client is not using
>   security.

What I dont know is how to get around this issue.
The system needs to use Basic Authentication and must use Soap 1.2(thus the custom binding).
I do not have control of the calling Java Client, but I am assured that it is calling the service using basic Auth.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am no Java expert but as far as I know, Java clients cannot implement SOAP 1.2 on the fly. And Java clients need external libraries to supplement the necessary policy/security headers in the 1.2 SOAP message.

I have directed my Java clients to use Metro libraries in order to consume my WCF service. (I am using a similar binding just like yours.) Here is a [blog](http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop) how to include [Metro](http://metro.java.net/) libraries.

Here is the MSDN link for [interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ff521748).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the java client to send a username token to the server. turn on Fiddler and compare the working soap (wcf client) to the non working one (java)